# Holdout vs K-fold

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation

I am working with 15k image dataset for binary classification. This is a patient-based medical image dataset. Is it enough to use a randomized holdout strategy (train, validation, and test)? Should I use k-fold cross-validation (test and train(10-fold))? Which is best for this amount of image dataset.
TIA

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of k-fold is that it gives you a better idea of how your model will generalise in the real world.

If you plan to make a model that is useful in the real world I recommend using a k-fold cross validation approach (or a [leave p out](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) approach if you have time), so that you can construct some [nonparametric confidence intervals](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-machine-learning-results-python/) for your model.

In each fold you can split the training data into training and validation if you need a validation set, e.g. for early stopping.